# Get all foreign keys from ORM query in parent table - Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have 2 models like such:

```
class Volunteer(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50L)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50L)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100L)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100L)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=2L)
    zip = models.CharField(max_length=5L)
    skype = models.CharField(max_length=50L)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50L)
    age = models.IntegerField(max_length=2L)
    phone_mobile = models.CharField(max_length=50L)
    phone_home = models.CharField(max_length=50L)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1)


class Assignment(models.Model):
    volunteer = models.ForeignKey(Volunteer)
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department)
    role = models.ForeignKey(Role)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=100L, blank=True, null=True)
```

I'm trying to get all volunteers as well as their assignment. The following works:

```
volunteers = Volunteer.objects.all().order_by('last_name')
for volunteer in volunteers:
    assignment = Assignment.objects.get(volunteer=volunteer)
    volunteer.assignment = assignment
```

But is there a more Django way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current model structure, each volunteer can have multiple assignments. So there is no such thing as "the" assignment for a volunteer. Perhaps you meant to use a OneToOneField instead of a ForeignKey, in which case you would automatically get an "assignment" accessor from Volunteer, making your loop redundant.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you. How would I reflect a `OneToOneField`? Would I do `volunteer = models.OneToOneField(Volunteer)` in `Assignment` or the inverse in `Volunteer`? Is there even a difference?

Comment: No, there is no real difference - it just depends where you want the information to be stored. Since your ForeignKey is on Assignment, you might as well keep the new field there.

Answer (score 1):

You can get all assignements of volunteer by using FOO_set, more [here in docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward):

```
volunteer.assignement_set.all()
```